# django self,pk for success function after save()

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I may be going about this backwards but I'm trying to use a pk in a success function to create a href to load.

The pk will be new and have been created by the save()
what I want to know is how to post the self.pk pack to the js to use it.
The javascript

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/add/res/",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),

    success: function(response) {
        var successMessage = $('<div>').text('New Personnel file created in database...').css({'color':'green', 'padding':'5px'}).addClass('pull-right');
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
            $('#submitresource').html('Added!').addClass('btn-success')
            $('.modal-row' ).append(successMessage);
            $.get('newres_pk'),
            window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href ="'/Personnel/results.html?id="+newres_pk+"'"},3000)              
        },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json"
    })

def set(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    res = Resource.objects.create(
        title=data['title'],
        preferred_name=data['preferred_name'],
        last_name=data['last_name'],
        employstatus=data['employstatus'],
        employer=Employer.objects.get(employer_name=data['employer']),
        role=Role.objects.get(role_name=data['role']), 
        location=Location.objects.get(name=data['location']), 
        workphone=data['workphone'], 
        mobile_phone=data['mobile_phone'],
        email=data['email'], 
        notes=data['notes'], 
        updated_by=data['updated_by'], 
    )

    res.save()

    newres_pk = res.pk


    print res

    return HttpResponse('"Submitted"', content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When return you can include the data you want to send by ex:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
data = {'message':'your message'}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

and in the javascript ..

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.message);
```

Comment: well as I have the '"Submitted"' to make everything function when I add the data as well i.e.    return HttpResponse(data, '"submitted"', content_type='application/json')  I get the error __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'content_type' Request Method: POST Request URL:

Comment: Why not use JsonResponse instead of HttpResponse ? Anyway you want json in the frontend so use JsonResponse ...

Comment: and how would that look. sorry Im pretty new

Comment: Thanks very much, I just need to do some tweaking on the data I'm sending but works a treat.